# AWS Batch run ECR repository error: exec /usr/local/bin/python3: exec format error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr, aws-batch

I have an AWS Batch job that returns the following error when it attempts to run a Docker image in ECR:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/python3: exec format error
```

I built the image on macOS with an M1 chip. Because of this I built the image with the following command using the `--platform linux/amd64` parameter. I have also tried `--platform linux/x86_64`:

```
docker buildx build --no-cache --platform linux/amd64 -t repository-name:latest .
```

I then ran `docker inspect --format='{{.Architecture}}' repository-name:latest` and it returned `arm64`. The CPU architecture for the container is X86_64. **Is this where my issue lies, and if so, what is incorrect with my build step?**

This is my Docker file:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python3", "/usr/src/app/hello_world.py"]
```

This is my hello_world.py script:

```
import pandas as pd

print('hello world!')
```

Additional troubleshooting:

1. Ran `docker run -it <image> bash` to verify the `/usr/src/app` path is correct.
2. Verified the path of the Python3 binary within docker, `which python3`.
3. Ran the image, `python3 /usr/src/app/hello_world.py` and the output was correct.
4. Deleted and recreated jobs, job definitions and repositories.

I hope this is enough detail to help me troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

> exec format error

This error is typical of mismatched CPU architectures, so yes your assumption is correct.

Your command to build the container image for Intel/AMD 64-bit is correct. I suspect that you are using a mismatched container image tag when you're attempting to deploy the container to the AWS Batch service. Make sure that when you run the `inspect` command, you are referencing the same tag as the `build` command, instead of using the `latest` tag every time. That's probably why you're seeing inconsistent results.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "mismatched container image tag"? I am using :latest when I build and inspect.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Gotcha, I noticed in your OP, you used `tag` and `latest`, so I thought it was possible you were using different values for those. That could have led to the inconsistency in your experience. If you specify `linux/amd64` in the `build`, then your resulting image should certainly be the same value.

Comment: ok. I updated the build command for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I reached a solution. Despite using `--no-cache` in the build command, local layers were apparently cached and after I ran `docker system prune -a`, built again and inspected the build, it was in the correct architecture, amd64. I pushed to the repository and it ran correctly.